# Ionic 4 Push notification popup is not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am trying to integrate FCM Push notifications in my ionic 4 project. What i did is just installed this plugin, followed instructions (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm#usage) and got FCM token. Below is my code to get token.

```
this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
    console.log('token', token)
});
```

Above code runs completely fine and prints FCM token in console. After that i am sending test notification from firebase console using that token. I am getting notification on device but the notification popup(Like whatsapp or other apps shows when you are using phone and new notification comes in) is not showing. New notification is silently being added in notification list of my phone. A small icon of my app is also showing on statusbar of the device. The issue is notification popup is not showing.

Below are the plugin versions that are being added in my package.json

> "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^4.1.1"
>
> "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.18.0"

I have created new project so this is the only plugin that i have installed so far in this project.

Also tried by sending push using postman using below data(and by modifying those data) but popup is not showing. Just a notification being added in list and small icon showed on statusbar of device.

```
{
    "to":"mydevicetoken",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Tag Test 6",
        "body": "test2",
        "sound":"default",
        "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    },
    "data":{
        "alertTitle": "title1",
        "alertBody": "test2",
        "leadId":"5dd6328c61e8f96ea9718419",
        "leadName": "Test Name"
    }
}
```

**Notification Popup**

[image]

Does anyone knows how to fix it or what i am doing wrong here?